# SQL LIKE wildcard assistance

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help with a simple query that I have but not sure how change the LIKE wildcard accordingly. This to query an Oracle database.

Could you please assist with the below,

```
select * from table_name
where field1 like '1%'
    or field2 like '2%'
    or field3 like '3%'
    or field4 start with 4 but not 4123
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * 
from table_name 
where field1 like '1%' 
or field2 like '2%' 
or field3 like '3%' 
or (field4 like '4%' and field4 not like '4123%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach:

```
select *
from table_name
where
  substr (field1, 1, 1) in ('1', '2', '3', '4') and
  field1 not like '4123%'
```